# Rendering in white

Tags: rendering

I've tried to add a sky background following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/Tr6wTyfAO04) but it renders totally white (preview is ok). I searched for similar problems but can't find the answer.
Here's the link to the file(s)
[Blender Files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxBRmMnKdkzFZHpiRlpjSUFKVnM)

Comment: In my computer, with your Blend files, it renders fine. It took 9 seconds with octacore CPU to render 1 frame. With GPU it worked also and it took about 4 seconds for the same frame.
Are you using Blender Render or Cycles Render?

Comment: Cycles render. I wonder if it's a graphics card issue. I'm currently trying to do it on a works computer which probably isn't man enough to handle it. I'll try on my home comp later and report back. Thanks

Comment: Make sure your not in orthographic view. Probably not the problem but it's a stupid mistake I made a while ago.

Comment: If you do render, it doesn't care if you are in ortho view or pespective view, it will be the camera view. Instead of rendering with GPU, try to render with the CPU?

Comment: renders fine here too... what is the effective problem? "rendering in white"... what? the house walls ARE white(ish)... what exactly is happening, please show a picture...

Comment: Your file has no issues and renders fine. Are you using an AMD-ATI GPU? Also in the future please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload files.

Comment: It looks like it was graphics card/cpu issue. I rendered it at home on my high spec PC and it worked fine. Thanks for your help everyone